# SWT lining up ICON_WARNING with Label

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I want to add a Composite to Eclipse that appears when a certain checkbox is checked. The composite will be comprised of 2 parts: a WARNING_ICON and a label with some text.

I can't seem to get the layout quite right - I want to display the image and label side by side. Here's my section of the code:

```
        final Composite warningComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        warningComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        warningComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(0, 0, true, false));

        Label l = SWTUtilities.createLabel(composite, "", -1, -1, 1, GridData.BEGINNING);
        final Image img = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_WARNING);
        l.setImage(img);
        l.setLayoutData(new GridData());

        l = SWTUtilities.createLabel(composite, "Wizards Gone Wild", -1, -1, 1, GridData.END);
```

And the SWTUtilities.createLabel method:

```
public static Label createLabel(final Composite parent, final String label, final int width, final int indent, final int span, final int style) {
        Assert.isNotNull(parent);
        Assert.isNotNull(label);
        final Label control = new Label(parent, SWT.WRAP);
        control.setText(label);
        if (width > 0 || indent > 0 || span > 0) {
            final GridData data = new GridData(style);
            if (width > 0)
                data.widthHint = width;
            if (indent > 0)
                data.verticalIndent = indent;
            if (span > 1)
                data.horizontalSpan = span;
            control.setLayoutData(data);
        }
        return control;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display d = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(d);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    Label image = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    image.setImage(d.getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_WARNING));
    image.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    Label text = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    text.setText("SOME TEXT HERE");
    text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, true));


    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
        while (!d.readAndDispatch())
            d.sleep();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

---

Here is the explanation: SWT does not support vertical alignment of text within the `Label` (because not all OSs support it). The solution is to align the label at the center of the parent, rather than the text within the label.